# IS NULL is not working for certains data types but IS NOT NULL works

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, isnull

I'm running a query in SQL Server 2014 (v12.0.5203) but it got to my attention the following results, here my query :

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
    [CustomerID], [NameStyle], [Title],
    [LastName], [Suffix], [CompanyName],
    [SalesPerson], [EmailAddress], [ModifiedDate]
FROM 
    [AdventureWorksLT2012].[SalesLT].[Customer]
WHERE 
    NameStyle = 0
    AND (([Suffix] IS NULL) 
         OR (MiddleName IS NOT NULL 
         AND ModifiedDate > '20030901'))
```

This way I'm only getting the results when `[Suffix] IS NULL`, ignoring the

```
OR
(MiddleName IS NOT NULL 
AND ModifiedDate > '20030901'
```

but if I change the

```
[Suffix] IS NULL by [Suffix] IS NOT NULL
```

it's working as expected, showing both results, I did also replace the `Suffix` (`varchar`) with `ModifiedDate` (`Datetime`) using

```
IS NULL AND IS NOT NULL,
```

and it worked. I was able to resolve my issue breaking down the queries and then using an UNION ALL but not sure if I'm doing something wrong on the query or the IS NULL is not working properly for certain data types(don't think it is), I would really appreciate if someone can explain me why this happen.

Thanks

and it's working in both ways

Comment: What's an example of a row that should be returned and isn't?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: The most likely explanation is that your data isn't what you think it is.   I promise you that IS NULL works as expected, and it works for all datatypes.

Comment: I'd bet that [Suffix] is a string and you think that an empty string is a null string, which are actually quite different things

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you without sample data and expected result , we can't guess what you need or what happen , and also can't assume if you want `OR` or `AND`

Comment: and what is the `len(suffix)` of a record that you think is null?  and if you wrap it in `rtrim(ltrim(suffix)) is null` do you get back what you want?  AND... you said, "this way I'm only getting the results when [Suffix] IS NULL ignoring the OR (MiddleName IS NOT NULL 
AND ModifiedDate > '20030901'"  Can you show us a record where suffix is not null and middle name has a value and the date is > 20030801.  and is modifieddate a date or a varchar?

Comment: @TabAlleman I think that op might be confused with the `OR` and `AND`s

Comment: @Lamak Yeah, mybe, but as I say before we can't guess :)

Comment: My bad guys, in fact the query is working as expected, the data that is being generated by the second condition is being removed by the first one due to the fact that results appears in the first condition. thanks all for your answers

Answer (score 0):

So ...

```
OR (MiddleName IS NOT NULL AND ModifiedDate > '20030901')
```

Is combining the middle name and modified date filters together.  If most records don't have a middlename (it is null) then you won't get many records.

Your code

```
(([Suffix] IS NULL) 
OR (MiddleName IS NOT NULL AND ModifiedDate > '20030901'))
```

Is returning results that that have no suffix or have a middle name and a modified date in range.

I think you want

```
(([Suffix] IS NULL OR MiddleName IS NOT NULL) 
AND ModifiedDate > '20030901')
```

This will give you everything after 2003-9-1 which has no suffix or has a middle name.